# How to get value with Selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a problem with extraction this "5" value.
`<div class="text">5</div>`

I tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="text"]').text`
but this don't gave me anything

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: no error but also no value. This print nothing

Comment: Upload the source code and the platform/page you are testing

Comment: Possibly there are some blank element with the same class name in your DOM. As you are using //* in your xpath so it find any tag with the given class attribute and return first element. Solution would be, make locator robust and unique to locate intended element.

Comment: @NarendraR thanks a lot. When i make `driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="text"]')` i get the list of values which have the same class. Now i can find my "5" value in this list